# Selenium driver closed when used with a Proxy

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, proxy

I am trying to use Selenium with a proxy to log into a company site. If I dont use Proxy the driver and code works perfectly fine. When I use the proxy the page opens and immediately closes.

```
from selenium import webdriver

HOSTNAME = 'proxy.froxy.com' 
PORT = '9000'
HEADLESS_PROXY = HOSTNAME + ":" + PORT
webdriver.DesiredCapabilities.EDGE['proxy'] = {
    "httpProxy": HEADLESS_PROXY,
    "sslProxy": HEADLESS_PROXY,
    "proxyType": "MANUAL",
}

with webdriver.Edge() as driver:
    driver.get("https://www.SomeDomain.com/account/login")
```

I can keep page open if I add this after driver.get

```
while(true):
   pass
```

But by adding that line then the python interpreter does not come back so i can not run any more commands unless I kill the process at which time my session with selenium is destroyed and cant continue anyway.

Answer (score 0):

OK here is what worked for me. For Froxy.com
I had to install selenium-wire and use below syntax using python version 3.9.12

```
from seleniumwire import webdriver

## Define Your Proxy Endpoints
proxy_options = {
    'proxy': {
       
        'https': 'http://{YOUR_PASSWROD}:wifi;us;;;@proxy.froxy.com:9001',
        'no_proxy': 'localhost:127.0.0.1'
    }
}

driver = webdriver.Edge(seleniumwire_options=proxy_options)
```